# how to install older version of firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I install the old version of a firebase in REACT app that is v8 instead of v9? I'm practicing on some old projects in which the syntax for an older version of firebase is used, so as a beginner it's really cumbersome to use the v9 for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import and use older versions of firebase by using 'firebase/compat'.

Importing firebase v8:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

In theory, you should be able to just rewrite all your firebase 8 imports like this and have your code working just fine.